# Calculating fibers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How do I show that the following is indeed true?
$$f^{-1}(A \space \backslash \space B)=f^{-1}(A) \space \backslash \space f^{-1}(B)$$
where the fiber $f^{-1}$ is defined as
$$ f^{-1}(A) := \{x \in D \space | \space f(x) \in A \}$$
with D being the function's domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule:

$$x\in f^{-1}(C)\iff f(x)\in C$$

On base of this rule prove that: $$x\in f^{-1}(A\backslash B)\iff x\in f^{-1}(A)\backslash f^{-1}(B)$$